# How to label line features dynamically with its length?

Tags: labeling, length, dynamic

I need to label a line feature with its length dynamically so the displayed length will be updated as I edit the line geometry. Is this possible in either QGIS or ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `$length` as your label.

This labels your lines with their length using the layer CRS' units - so if you use a degree-based CRS, your length will be in degree.